# NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Tags: python, mysql, executable, mysql-python, sql-authentication

I use the following line of code in order to connect to a database instance of my computer.

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=Host, user=User, password=Password, database=db, auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
```

The connection works perfectly both at the the spyder console and at the executable (.exe) that I made from this code. The problem is that when I try to run this executable remotely from another computer and connect to the database instance of my computer (my IP) I get this authentication plugin error. Should I change something to the settings of mysql database? I need the code to run both locally at my PC and remotely at any other.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error while connecting to MySql database as :

in get_auth_plugin mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Which had removed by using windows command line window:

```
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python
```

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```